# How to know open successful browser or error by using command window

Tags: java, windows, command-line

I have a function to open browser via .exe file and command window.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    if(location.contains("iexplore")){
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(location+" "+ url);
    }else{
        String[] commandLine = { location, " "
                + url };
           Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);

    }



} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("openURL() ", e);
}
```

It work if the location=C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe. But the author can choose file .exe in anywhere. Ex: location=C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\safari.exe and the returned results is a popup error:

[image]

How to prevent the popup show. using try/catch does not work.